# Find substring in a string

Tags: c, string

Here is my code to find substring entered by the user in the given string.

```
bool find_str(char *str, char const *substr) {
    while(*str) {
        if(*str++ == *substr) {
            char const *a = substr;
            while((*str++ == *++a));  /*empty*/
            if(*a == '\0')
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
// If match found, then return true, else false

int main(void) {
  printf("%d", find_str("ABCDEF", "CDE"));  /* Return true in this case */
  printf("%d", find_str("ABCDE", "CDE")); /* Return false in this case */

}
```

As explained in the comment, it returns true whenever it ends with an additional characters. If it is not, then it returns false. I think there is a problem in increment/decrement operator. But I could not find how?

Comment: *str++, *++a, got me reaching scratching my head trying to remember operator precedence. I don't like remembering things. Either comment it or add some brackets ().

Comment: Here how it works, first it compare A with C, then with B with C until C == C, so in the nested while it increment with a side-effect making D == D and E == E.(*++a first point to D, whereas *str++ also point to D but increment after)

Comment: This is not a code review site.  Anyway, `strstr` does this - 10 seconds google-foo and you can find implementations e.g. http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/libsa/strstr.c .  In your code, there's several bugs: to learn to find them, I recommend putting trace like `printf("'%s' =?= '%s'\n", str, a);` where you're doing your comparisons... you'll pretty soon see what you're really comparing and realise what's wrong, then you can reason and experiment to fix it.  Hint: as Apple did, keep the is-the-a-match-here logic separate from look-everywhere-along-str: `strncmp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your code decides to stop on finding `\0` only *after* performing the comparison

```
*str++ == *++a
```

This condition will be `true` even when the match happens at the end of the string on null terminators, so the `while` loop would happily proceed beyond the end of both strings past the null terminator, causing undefined behavior.

Changing the condition to exit when `*a` is zero should fix the problem:

```
while((*str++ == *++a) && (*a));
```

Comment: Thanks for debugging, it was so simple

Comment: @ashish2expert: As an aside (and prompted by the @John3136 comment), I think a slight change would make this more easy to read for most programmers: `char const *a = substr+1; while(*a && (*str++ == *a++)) {};`

Answer (score 1):

I analysed you piece of code a little bit and based on my analysis,
I think the problem is in here

```
        while((*str++ == *++a));    /*empty*/
```

perhaps you would like to add another statement like below

```
while((*str++ == *++a) && ( *a != '\0' ) ) ;    /*empty*/
```

I guess you are missing a null check, what if both pointer are pointing to NULL termination they will still go forward that's exactly whats happening

I was going through your piece of code and found quite a few interesting things

1. Lets say the memory allocated for CDE is at X
2. say again the memory allocated for ABCDEF is at X+4 (this was the case in my machine)
3. and say memory block allocated for ABCDE is at some X+Y or what ever

now when the function is called second time 
both pointers a and str point to respective memory locations starting at X+2 where Character C satisfies the condition above, however the condition will still be true even if they reach to end i.e at X+3 and hence a will move forward and point to A which makes your program behave erroneously